# What filter or action hook to use in order to load some code before the template begins printing in BuddyPress?

Tags: templates, filters, hooks, buddypress, actions

I would like to load some code before the template begins printing in BuddyPress. What filter or action hook should I use?

I tried a number of them (such as `bp_head`, `bp_include`, `bp_init`), but none of them seem to work. My code is simply never loaded.

The list of filters and action hooks is hundreds of entries long, which is a bit overwhelming to me, since I am fairly new to BuddyPress. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to tell BuddyPress to use a different template if certain conditions are met. So I have some code in bp-custom.php and I would need the appropriate filter or action hook to get it working. Preferably one that accepts a `$template` variable as an argument.

EDIT: I've tried with different action priority numbers (or without) and nothing seems to work. Still need help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I'd start with something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'your_function', 3 );
function your_function(){
    if ( is_page_template( 'some-template.php' ) ) { 
        if( some condition ) 
            locate_template( array( 'some-other-template.php' ), true );
        else
            return;
    }
    else 
        return;
}
```

Comment: The `wp` action trigger doesn't work either :(

Comment: Try changing or removing the action priority number.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either :(

Comment: Tried it in the `functions.php` page instead of `bp-custom.php` and it works like a charm! Thanks! :)